# Disable next link when last page reached in data tables pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I am using datatables jquery plugin for pagination on table. I want to disable the previous link if the first page is loaded and disable next page link if last page is reached.Is there any way to achieve this. Thanks.
Am using it like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#OrdersTable').dataTable( {
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
  });
});
```

Comment: That is the default behaviour, in my experience. Are your row count values displaying correctly?

Comment: Am showing only the previous and next buttons.

Comment: markpsmithis right. Can you create fiddle that reproduces the behaviour? Or link to a site?

Comment: Have a look at an example that is working properly, e.g [http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html). Use firebug to inspect the 'previous' link on page 1, note 'disabled' class. That's the default behaviour.

Comment: Or just post a sample of your HTML.